# Why are these aggregate sums different?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentTime]
([StudentTimeID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(164352, 1),
 [StudentID] [int] NOT NULL,
 --Some columns...
 [EntryDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [Hours] [decimal] (6, 2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_StudentTime_Hours] DEFAULT ((0))
 --Some more columns
 )
```

When I query it

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT StudentID) AS StudentCount,
SUM(HOURS) AS TotalHours
FROM dbo.StudentTime
WHERE EntryDateTime >= '5/1/2010'
AND EntryDateTime < '5/1/2011'
```

I get this result:

```
StudentCount: 9890
TotalHours: 775645.5
```

Now I want to filter students out of the count, who for whatever reason, have accumulated 0 hours in that reporting period:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT StudentID) AS StudentCount,
SUM(HOURS) AS TotalHours
FROM dbo.StudentTime
WHERE EntryDateTime >= '5/1/2010'
AND EntryDateTime < '5/1/2011'
AND Hours > 0
```

I get this result:

```
StudentCount: 9792 --Expected to be smaller.
TotalHours: 775699.25 --Expected to be same, but is larger?!?!
```

Is it because I have `AND Hours > 0` (An INT) vs `AND Hours > 0.0` (a DECIMAL)?  When I do this where statement, is there an implicit CAST going on?

Comment: What is the result of this query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StudentTime WHERE Hours < 0` ?

Comment: 34 records.  I wonder if that is it?  There is no constraint saying that the EntryDateTime must be greater than the ExitDateTime (Not shown), either in the application code or the DB.

Comment: Bingo, CodeNaked, the sum of negative hours is -54 or so.  If you post an answer, I will accept.  :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sum is larger when you exclude certain records, then you must be excluding negative numbers.

Keep in mind that they sum of [1, -1, 2] is 2, since `1 + (-1) + 2 == 1 - 1 + 2`.

As you point out, if the end date and start date are not correct, then you may also exclude records you intended to be included. This may result in a larger or smaller sum than expected as well.

Answer (score 3):

You must have some negative hours.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with live data?  Even if there are students with negative hours, the distinct student count should have decreased when you added another condition (hours > 0)

OK, I fell for your comment instead of the data.  The second result is smaller than the first.

Comment: That was why I added that condition.  You can store comments in that table with time of 0 hours.  I did not want to count those students in the aggregate sum.  I wasn't anticipating the existence negative time entries and their effects of this query.